# Show that $E[X]=\frac{2}{\lambda}$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, definite-integrals

Given $f_\lambda(x)=\lambda^2xe^{-\lambda x}$ $x\geq0$, show that $E[X]=\frac{2}{\lambda}$.

I think that the expectation can be calculate with: $$E[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty} x\cdot\lambda^2xe^{-\lambda x}dx$$

But if I solve this one with the calculator the result is undef., so I think that my integration limits are wrong, but I can't figured out why? Also because the lower is given and is $0$, can someone please help me?

Comment: "With the *calculator*"??  It is straightforward in computer algebra:  `Assuming[\[Lambda] > 0,
 Integrate[x^2 \[Lambda]^2 Exp[-\[Lambda] x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
 ]` $2/\lambda$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork you are right but I'm lazy to do with the pen and I don't know how to use computer algebra :)

Comment: Type "Integrate x^2 r^2 Exp[-r x], {x, 0, Infinity}" into WolframAlpha.com and be done with it!  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+x%5E2+r%5E2+Exp%5B-r+x%5D,+%7Bx,+0,+Infinity%7D

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'll try right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[X]=\int_0^{\infty}x\lambda^2xe^{-\lambda x}dx=\frac1{\lambda}\int_0^{\infty}\lambda^3x^2e^{-\lambda x}dx=\frac1{\lambda}\int_0^{\infty}y^2e^{-y}dy\text{ (by change of variable } y=\lambda x)=\frac1{\lambda}\Gamma(3)=\frac2{\lambda}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now it's clear!!